# Devise - how to allow change of unconfirmed email (correction) on verification page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm currently implementing Devise Confirmable so that a user is sent to the confirmations page "We've sent a validation email to , check it and click on the link".

I'm being asked to implement a feature that allows a user to edit that email in case they made a mistake, and for to update and send the verification to the new email. This would only be for brand-new accounts, and not existing ones with any data in them.

The user is not logged in before they verify, and I'm sending params[:uuid] to the page, which is getting wiped whenever it reloads - not a great way to do this. I could use localstorage, I suppose...

has anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you allow new users to access your app before confirming the email?

Comment: No, they are signed out until confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store unconfirmed account ID in the session on the server: `session[:unconfirmed_account] = 999`. And then, when a user is not authenticated and there is `session[:unconfirmed_account]` present, show a notification on the page with the account unconfirmed email and a link or a button to change it.

I think the best way to set `:unconfirmed_account` variable in the session is by overriding Devise's `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` method. This is where a new unconfirmed account is created.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      if resource.persisted?
        session[:unconfirmed_account] = resource.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The information about how to customize `Devise` controllers can be found here https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise#Configuring_controllers

Once the user has confirmed the email and is authenticated, the session variable should be deleted.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    super do |resource|
      if resource.errors.empty?
        session.delete(:unconfirmed_account)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When the user updates the unconfirmed email, the account should be updated and a new confirmation message should be sent to the new email address. This is for you to implement )

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is,

For example,

1. if the user is sent a confirmation mail with a link, and he clicks on the link, at this point you could have a status column which would change the status to `pending`.
2. Now, you could allow the users to change their email until the status of their account remain `pending`. At this point, if the user wants to go back and change his email, he will and receive a confirmation mail with a link.
3. Let's assume we have a `approved` status, this will change from `pending` to `approved` only after he signs into the application.

Did this help ?